# React couldn't upload same image twice

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a code that lets me upload images to react-easy-crop package. I also have an "x" button that removes the image so the user can reupload another image. The problem I'm facing now is that when the user removes an uploaded image, they are unable to re-upload the same image.

The code for the upload component:

```
const onSelectFile = (event: any) => {
   if (event.target.files && event.target.files.length > 0) {
      if (!allowedFileTypes.some(x => x === event.target.files[0].type || event.target.files[0].size > 10000000) {
         setImage('')
         setError('Failed to upload. Inccorect size or file type');
      }
      else {
         setError('')
         reader.readDataAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
         reader.addEventListener("load", () => {
            setImage(reader.result as string);
         });
      }
```

and for the remove button, i did this:

```
const onRemoveImg = () => {
   setImage('')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With these few info I have to guess...
Try to use  `.createObjectURL` instead of `fileReader`, it is synchronous, but it ight help you to debug if that particular issue depends from fileReader being stuck if you try to read the same file twice...

```
const onSelectFile = (event: any) => {
   if (event.target.files && event.target.files.length > 0) {
      if (!allowedFileTypes.some(x => x === event.target.files[0].type || event.target.files[0].size > 10000000) {
         setImage('')
         setError('Failed to upload. Inccorect size or file type');
      }
      else {
         setError('')
         const img : string = window.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0])
         setImage(img);
         });
      }
```

Comment: Hi yes, that seems to be the case when trying to read the same file twice, the file reader got stuck. Perhaps it might be the image source that needs to be directly modified to properly remove an image?

It's in another component where it will be saved as a blob

Comment: I'd try with createObjectURL and revoke the URL on reset. In most cases that's enough!